# ¿se pueden "anidar" suscesivos <form action="...">?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estoy desarrollando una típica página de perfil de usuario donde entre otras cosas tengo el dilema de subir una foto de perfil. Además hay datos que van a traves de una acción "post" a otro archivo php donde procesa la informacion.
Ahora bien, resulta que encontré una herramienta que se llama jcrop y que es con la que se recorta una fotografía. Me gustaría que el usuario ingresara unicamente fotos recortadas. Pero hete aquí que esa herramienta jcrop tiene su propio metodo post es decir tiene su propio form... 
la pregunta es, si yo tengo esta estructura:

```
<form action="actualizar.php" method="post">

    (ACA IRIA TODOS LOS INPUT)

    <form action="crop.php" method="post">
        (ACA IRIAN LOS CAMPOS QUE NECESITO PARA RECORTAR LA IMAGEN)
    </form>


</form>
```

¿se puede hacer?

Comment: Creo que si, con que prevengas el submit de cada forma tu página no se recargará, pero si se procesará la forma, habría de hacer la prueba

Comment: ¿ya lo probaste? ¿cuál fue el resultado?

Comment: no, todavía no lo probé... quería saber si "está bien hacer eso así"... pensé por ahi que sería más "prolijo" tratar el form de la imagen, fuera del form principal. Es decir:

Comment: <form action="crop.php" method="post">
    (ACA IRIAN LOS CAMPOS QUE NECESITO PARA RECORTAR LA IMAGEN)
</form>

<form action="actualizar.php" method="post">
    (ACA IRIA TODOS LOS INPUT)
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola como dicen por ahí divide y vencerás,

primero recibes los datos de la persona junto con la imagen normal una vez que ya tienes capturado los datos.

segundo envías al usuario a una segunda pagina en donde puede editar su imagen, pones un campo oculto o atravez de sessiones, guardas el id de la persona para actualizar si imagen de perfil.

saludos

Comment: GENIAL... gracias Rauls !!!

Answer (score 0):

La unica forma de que funcione es que el form interno sea procesado por separado en background usando Ajax por ejemplo de modo que no afecte el estado del primer formulario.

Comment: y si trato primero el form de la imagen y luego el form principal ?

Comment: Si envias el form principal, este sera procesado por el crop.php y luego se renderizara el resultado de la pagina cron.php en lugar del formulario anterior, es decir todo el formulario en blanco.